# Other ways of implementing Crashplan on a LAMP setup

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, graphical-user-interface

I've got a LAMP setup running Ubuntu 12.04 server and I'd like to integrate it with CrashPlan that I use on all my other mac xserves that I'm running. The problem is that it has to run a gui application to set all the preferences and configurations. CrashPlan has an 'unsupported' tutorial on how to spoof ports and use ssh tunneling with the gui running on a desktop. I'd prefer not to do this.

Options I see are to either install a gui and somehow turn it off except when running the desktop app, or something else. Maybe theres a way to only use some sort of virtual vnc or something. I've found tutorials on installing full Gnome, XFCE and KDE, but what other options are more friendly with a server implementation that can be easily turned on and off from the cli.

Answer (score 1):

Just ssh to the box with X11 forwarding enabled.  The GUI will show up on the machine you connect from.